# gulp-git returning "Command failed: fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git"

Tags: git, gulp

I am running Gulp on CentOS 7 using the gulp-git plugin for deployments, and everything has been working just fine, until randomly gulp-git started returning

```
Command failed: fatal: 
Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

when I try to pull my repository from the remote.

As far as I know nothing has changed. It was working just fine for weeks and now doesn't.

I've tried rebooting the server. I deleted the entire folder that has the .git repo and reinitialized it. I was able to manually fire a `git pull`, it only fails when I try from within Gulp.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are in the git folder?
is it git repository?

This error mean that you are trying to execute git commands outside of your git project folder.

Comment: Yes, a little more digging and I was looking in the wrong folder. It was a git repository, but seems it has gotten corrupted somehow. Guess I have to figure out why gulp-git is corrupting the repository.